Twilio conversation to Conference call from Simple call
I want to add users to simple call generated using twilio to update it to conference call
 public function forwardCallToUser(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);
        $conferenceName = 'Conference_' . time() . '_' . rand(1000, 9999);
        $newUser = User::findOrFail($newUserId);
        $newUserNumber = $newUser->phone_number;
        $call = $client->calls($ongoingCallSid)->fetch();
            $twiml = new VoiceResponse();
            $dial = $twiml->dial('');
            $dial->conference($conferenceName, [
                'startConferenceOnEnter' => true,
                'endConferenceOnExit' => false,
            ]);
            $client->calls($ongoingCallSid)->update([
                'twiml' => $twiml->asXML()
            ]);

            $message = 'Converted existing call to conference and added new participant
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'conference_name' => $conferenceName,
            'new_participant_sid' => $newCall->sid,
            'message' => $message
        ]);
}

it is giving me error
"[HTTP 400] Unable to fetch record: Invalid CallSid: CH8284f315ba6e43f1822e4efec9708bd1"
even though ongoing call sid is same as mentioned above
I want to integrate adding user to simple call and make it conference call using twilio

It seems you're putting in the wrong sid. The prefix "CH" indicates that this sid belongs to a conversations resource. Call sid should start with CA.
